# def inside def or how to do it

Tags: ruby

I would like to make something like this:

```
class Result<<ActiveRecord::Base

  def condensation
    #some code here that calculates @winner and @looser and @condresalut
    def winner
      @winner
    end

    def looser
      @looser
    end

    def showresault
      @condresalut
    end
  end

end
```

so that I can call `res.condensation.winner` and `res.condensation.looser` and `res.condensation.showresault`.

What is the best way to do it? Apparently this way it does not work, I got nils.

Comment: yes...sorry...it is...but it does not work this way...is it even possible to have def inside def?

Comment: retagged this as it really has nothing to do with anything except for Plain Old Ruby.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is indeed possible to do so.  Not sure what the intent is, as that has been asked, but not sure if that question was clarified.

However Jay Fields has a [well visited blog entry](http://blog.jayfields.com/2008/02/ruby-dynamically-define-method.html) that shows how to define a method inside a method.

```
class Class
 def def_each(*method_names, &block)
   method_names.each do |method_name|
     define_method method_name do
        instance_exec method_name, &block
     end
   end
 end
end
```

Your methods themselves inside your definition though are likely better served using the `attr_reader` technique.

As far as calling nested defined methods:

```
def testing
  def testing2
    'it worked'
  end
end

puts testing::testing2
```

Thogh as [Alex D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/960828/alex-d) reminds me in the comments, the scope operator is a deception.

Comment: While this reduces code when defining methods inside another method, how does it address how to call the internally defined methods from outside the wrapping method, per the OPs question "...so that I can call res.condensation.winner and res.condensation.looser and res.condensation.showresault" Creating the embedded methods isn't the real issue, it's how to call them discretely.

Comment: Thanks Tin Man... updated post.  scope operator, like normal.

Comment: The way you show to call the nested method, `testing::testing2`, is very deceptive. What actually happens when you do that, is it calls `testing`, which returns `nil`, then it evaluates `nil::testing2`, which is the same as `Object::testing2` (I believe). Try putting a `puts` inside `testing`, and you will see. Also try `nil::testing2` and `Object::testing2`.

Comment: Well, with it empty, it should return nil.  And yes, you can call it also by using Object::testing2.  Thanks for that.  To bring it further down, though, you can simply call testing2 and it is accessible.

Answer (score 2):

```
def condensation
  @condensation ||= Struct.new(:winner, :looser, :showresult).new
end

def winner
  @winner ||= condensation.winner
end

def winner=(winner)
  @winner = winner
end

... and so on
```

I changed resault by result, and I wanted to change showresult with show_result

You can calculate winner like this:

```
def calculate_winner
  # something using winner= method
end
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: That's the way you could call `res.condensation.winner` and `res.condensation.looser` and `res.condensation.showresault`

Comment: thank you, but where should I put my code that calculates @ winner and @ looser and @ condresalut? inside def condensation? and how do I set values?

Comment: Those are returning values, but not calling methods. It's not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: updated to set `@winner`. @thetinman, methods that return values that you can call, is not it?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can get there from here.

Ruby allows us to define methods inside methods, but the inner methods are not exposed, or available directly.

The inner methods are only available from within the outer method, so, in your example, `winner`, `looser` and `showresault` are only accessible from inside `condensation`.

You *could* create `lambdas` or `procs` and return them, en masse, as closures, which would give you access to the internal values inside `condensation`, but, really, it seems as if you're confusing the use of a class vs. a method and trying to make a method behave like a class with its accessors. Instead, I'd probably create a class within a class, and go from there.

Comment: but would not instance variable allow this to be available?